# Настройка .htaccess файла, единая точка входа

Tags: php, .htaccess, маршрутизация

Имеется структура папок:

```
localhost/
---> app (вся логика приложения)   
---> www (css, js, image, index.php - единая точка входа)
```

Как настроить `mod_rewrite`, чтобы все запросы перенаправлялись на `/www/index.php`, но при этом в адресной строке не было видно `/www/`?

Answer (score 1):

В localhost положить css, js, image, index.php и сделать структуру
**localhost**
**app**
и не выдумывать велосипедов

[https://www.google.ru/search?q=mod_rewrite+единая+точка+входа](https://www.google.ru/search?q=mod_rewrite%20%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url_param=$1 [L]
```

Comment: подскажите пжл, как настроить `mod_rewrite` для предложенной Вами структуры.